# Tag in post feature for social media application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a social network like application in **MVC ASP.Net**. I want to add a feature that people can tag their friends in their timeline posts as people can do on Facebook with @ sign.

[image: Facebook Tag feature]

I have designed most of the required modules like adding friends, creating groups, posting updates, pop-up chats but have no idea how can I add this feature that shows a dropdown list of my friends' names that are similar to the text after @ sign. Also how to implement that feature.
Please share if you have some idea or you know some tool so that I get some clue and design that feature.

[image: My Timeline posting interface where I want to add this feature.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this via `live search` in 3 simple steps.

1. What you have to do is capture an event `on-keypress` or `on-keydown`
2. After capturing the event send an AJAX call to your friend list and search through similar names in a `SQL like query` as `name like %Ade%` and decide how many records(names) you want to send back to your front end.
3. Render the response

I have also made a simple code in angular, you can implement this logic at your backend.
Here you go. If still got some issue let me know.

```js
angular.module('Search', [])
    .controller('SearchController', function($scope,) {
        $scope.all_records = ["Ali", "Ahmad", "Faraz", "Hassan"]

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Search">
<div ng-controller="SearchController">

Enter a name:
<input type="text" ng-model="search_term" on-keypress="you_need_to_call_a_method_here"/>

<p ng-repeat="x in all_records| filter: search_term ">{{x}}</p>



</div></div>
```